# Rename a table in c#

Tags: c#, rename, mdf

Hello how can I rename a table? I'm so newcomer on SQL.

Here is my code:

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connString))
{
    // string symbolName = dt.Rows[1][0].ToString();

    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(connString);
    command.CommandText = "ALTER TABLE test RENAME TO [" + symbolName + "]";
    command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
}
```

Comment: Please see [ask]. You are expected to show what research you have done.

Comment: What errors are you getting with the code you provided?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this: sp_rename

exec sp_rename 'schema.old_test', 'new_your_new_table_name'

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-rename-transact-sql

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add one more line

```
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```